# Software to create a bootable Windows USB installer in Zorin OS

Tags: linux, boot

Simple as it sounds, I have tried UNetbootin which will produce something that won't boot, as is balenaEtcher. I have tried WoeUSB that is way to complex for my limited knowledge of Linux, and won't work either.

I want a point-click-done GUI solution, like rufus for windows. Why should it be so hard to create a bootable usb?

Answer (score 1):

I've been there, friend; I can feel it. You can follow either of the methods mentioned below according to your convenience (I recommend No. 2):

1. **You can use the dd command to write the image to the disk.**

- `sudo dd bs=4M if=/path-to-image/image-name.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress && sync`
- ***points to note:***
- In place of sdx put your drive label(can be identified with command `lsblk` ).
- In 'if= ' put the file path for the iso image[for example: /home/harshu/downloads/windows.iso].
- In 'bs= ' you can put any amount but I recommend to keep it 4M.
- **NOTE**: This method might not always work for "*windows*" image files.

2. **You can use [ventoy](https://ventoy.net) and it is very easy to setup.**

- Download latest release of ventoy for linux ([you can find the latest release here](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy/releases)).
- Extract the zip content of the file you just downloaded.
- Open terminal in the ventoy folder and enter the following command:
  `sudo ./VentoyWeb.sh`
- Then go to 'http://127.0.0.1:24680' (as it is already mentioned in terminal after running VentoyWeb.sh, Warning do not click ctrl+C yet).
- select the desired drive and flash it.
- Then click ctrl+C in terminal.
- Now you can see that a drive named "Ventoy" has been mounted.
- Now copy the iso image file and paste it in **Ventoy** drive.
- after copying is finished boot from ventoy usb and select the desired iso file and you're good to go.
- You can also put multiple iso files if you have enough storage. Then whenever you boot from ventoy you can choose from multiple different .iso's .
- **NOTE**: Windows 7 iso might not work as per my experience any other iso mentioned over [here](https://ventoy.net/en/isolist.html) will definitely work.
- If you couldn't follow my guidance in this method, [here](https://ventoy.net/en/doc_linux_webui.html) is the website's guide.

I've gone through the exact same scenario as you, I was in zorin OS lite and I have tried the methods you have mentioned in the question and none of them worked for me too. Finally I made my brother flash it for me via rufus since he uses windows. Then flashing failed many times for that particular drive and Ultimately I landed on Ventoy and it worked like a charm.

***I hope this answer might help you.***